# Android AlarmManager doesn't ring on time on Sony and Xiaomi

Tags: android

I have written an android daily-repeating alarm app using AlarmManager class.
The app was tested on a bunch of test devices running on android 4.2 - 5.0. Most of testing results were good except that of Sony Xperia Z2 and Xiaomi Mi 3 running on android 4.4.4:

- Sony Xperia Z2: the alarm fired around 3 - 10 minutes later than the scheduled time. (A 9:10AM alarm would fire at around 9:13 - 9:20AM)
- Xiaomi Mi 3: a regular 3 minute delay could be observed.

Below is the code snippet of setting alarm:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
// if scheduled time < current time, add 1 day
if (Calendar.getInstance().compareTo(calendar) == 1) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

int alarmIntentId = 0;
int flag = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
long repeatInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmIntentId, intent, flag);

alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), repeatInterval, alarmIntent);
```

Does anyone have ideas and solutions about this delay issue? There are couple of other alarm apps that works on Sony and Xiamo like "Timely". Any advises would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Targeted API version changed to 18 and it has all worked.

Answer (score 1):

The alarm delivery is inexact since API 19, use the `setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)` Method for an exact alarm and set this on every day new.

Have you note this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Summary:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

setRepeat Method:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

I see the following line

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

So I guess by definition it is not exact.